# INNODB FULLTEXT search with JOIN: search term on different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, left-join, innodb

I used to use the following query with `MyISAM`:

```
SELECT *, table2.columnx 
FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.columnx_id = table2.id 
WHERE MATCH(table1.columny, table2.columnx) AGAINST("+key* +word*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This makes a `FULLTEXT` search on multiple tables.

Now, I switched to `INNODB` and I got the following error message:

> General error: 1210 Incorrect arguments to MATCH

I rewrote the query as follows to remove the error message and make it working:

```
SELECT *, table2.columnx 
FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.columnx_id = table2.id 
WHERE MATCH(table1.columny) AGAINST("+key* +word*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
      OR MATCH(table2.columnx) AGAINST("+key* +word*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This is working very well as long as all search terms `key` AND `word` are in the same table.

But if e.g. `key` is in `table1` and `word` is in `table1` I don't get any result.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Create 3rd table with this 2 columns and according references. Create FT index by this table and use it in the query. Update this table data by trigger logic.

Comment: @Akina I'll do that. But in general: Is this scenario possible or isn't this possible at all with `INNODB` but only with `MyISAM`?

Comment: I do not see the restriction which does not allow to use this technique on any engine (which supports FTS, of course).

Comment: @Akina I was speaking about my question, not your comment.

Comment: MATCH() needs the expression to search in which completely matches the expression in FT index. Index is an object which is a part of a table, it can use columns from this only table in its expression. So noway to create one FT index in InnoDB which combines the data from 2 separate tables.

Comment: @Akina So, if it's possible, why do you want me to create a third table with FULLTEXT index?

Comment: I combine these texts from two separate tables into one table which allows to create FTI.

Comment: @Akina I unterstand, what you mean. My question is: Do you `combine these texts from two separate tables into one table` because it's one (easy) possibility or is it the only possibility, because `INNODB` doesn't allow `FULLTEXT` search on two tables?

Comment: *is it the only possibility, because INNODB doesn't allow FULLTEXT search on two tables* - and I provide the logic which grounds this.

Comment: @Akina Thanks, this is what I wanted to know. If you post that as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by @Akina this doesn't seem to be possible because `INNODB` doesn't allow `FULLTEXT` search on two tables.

I'll create a third table only for the `FULLTEXT` search and fill that with the data from both tables.

Comment: Nor any other type of index.