# Fulltext Search with joined tables, show exact match "best match" first

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, innodb

What I must change in my query to get exact matches first?

For exampel, anyone is typing **Happy Song** in den Searchform, now he get this output..

Happy Children
Happy Days
Happy People
**Happy Song**
Happy Station
...

This is my query..

````
    SELECT  `artist`, `song`, `genre`, `pass`, `id`
        FROM  `songs`
        JOIN  `artists` USING (`pass`)
        WHERE  MATCH(`artist`) AGAINST("happy song")
          OR  MATCH(`song`, `genre`) AGAINST("happy song")
        ORDER BY  `song` ASC
        LIMIT  0,30
') or die(mysql_error($_connect));```

Thank you!

EDIT 03.07.22
Changed query to:<br>
```$query = mysqli_query($_connect, '
    SELECT  `artist`, `song`, `genre`, `pass`, `id`
        FROM  `songs`
        JOIN  `artists` USING (`pass`)
        WHERE  MATCH(`artist`) AGAINST("happy song")
          OR  MATCH(`song`, `genre`) AGAINST("happy song")
        ORDER BY  `song` = "happy song" DESC
') or die(mysql_error($_connect));```

The output is the same, result with only "song" in the text are above in the result when searched for "happy song"

**EDIT 14.7.22**
**Table Artists:**

CREATE TABLE `artists` (
  `artist` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `pass` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 PACK_KEYS=1;

ALTER TABLE `artists`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`pass`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `uni_que` (`artist`) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE `artists` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `full_txt` (`artist`);
COMMIT;

**Table Songs:**

    CREATE TABLE `songs` (
      `song` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
      `tags` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
      `style` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `pass` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 PACK_KEYS=1;
    
    ALTER TABLE `songs`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
    ALTER TABLE `songs` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `song` (`song`,`tags`,`style`);
    COMMIT;
````

Comment: The new query "looks" ok.  Please provide CREATE TABLEs for the two tables so I can test it.

Comment: Please qualify each column by which table it is in.

Comment: Look above edited today...Table ,,artists,, and Table ,,songs,,.

Comment: I tested now without ORDER BY and ,,happy song,, are now at second results position. How that can be? with ORDER BY the match is in the basement and without ORDER BY at the top :-|

Comment: I don't see `genre` in any of the tables!

Comment: I deleted this, no more exists...only song,style and tags

Answer (score 0):

You are currently asking for alphabetical ordering with `ORDER BY song ASC`

Change to `ORDER BY MATCH(...) AGAINST(...) DESC`

That may put "A song about happy kids" first.  That is, if you need "happy song" first, we will need to work harder:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY song = "happy song" DESC,
             MATCH(...) AGAINST (...)
```

(Since you have `OR` and multiple columns involved, the query is likely to get quite messy.)

If you don't want songs with only one of the words, see the `+` operator, or

```
MATCH(song) AGAINST('+"happy song"')
```

Note the deliberate usage of the quotes.

Comment: I used now: ORDER BY `song` = "happy song" DESC but the output is the same, many results with only "song" are above "happy song" for example...happy station is above searched happy song..

Comment: Try it with 2 parts in the ORDER BY.

Comment: how I can do this? sorry i'm new in mysql..thank you!

Comment: @BeKu - My example shows such.

Comment: Don't understand, cant see join etc in the example, if I use I become 500 internal server error........You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY `artist` = "happy+song" DESC, MATCH(`artist`) AGAINST("happy+song") OR ' at line 1

Comment: @BeKu - I have a list of two things in the `ORDER BY`.  The first is testing for exact match, which turns into `1` for true, hence the `DESCENDING`.  The second is a copy of the `MATCH`, but spelled out.  (It may also need `DESC`.)

Comment: Sorry I only have 500 error, dont work, I dont understand your code.......You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY `artist` = "happy+song" DESC, MATCH(`artist`) AGAINST("happy+song") OR ' at line 1

Comment: @BeKu - What is immediately before "ORDER"?

Comment: The query is the second above...but I read now that innodb not support fulltext search on joined tables? is this the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66237942/innodb-fulltext-search-with-join-search-term-on-different-tables